# Servlet, writing data

Tags: c#, java, linux, servlets, file-io

I had a servlet which was running on my local windows machine using local host. We have managed to get hold of one of our colleagues in America who is now hosting it on their Linux box so we can test the programme in a mimmicked real world environment for now.

However i seem to be getting an error, which i cant debug write now as my supervisor has gone for the day and i dont have access. We left it on the understanding i would do some investigation.

Just before he left i narrowed it down to these lines of code

```
file = File.createTempFile("temp", Long.toString(System.nanoTime()));
             out.print("Managed to make temp file in trst_servlet");
             FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
             ObjectOutputStream oos = xstream.createObjectOutputStream(writer, "ProcessedInformation");
         oos.writeObject(returnedSearchData);
         oos.flush();
         oos.close();

         out.print("object Persisted"); //PROGRAMME MAKES IT TO HERE
         response.setContentLength((int)(file.length()));
         FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);

         OutputStream ops = response.getOutputStream();

         byte[]buf = new byte[1024];
         int count = 0;
         while((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0)
         {
             ops.write(buf, 0, count);
         }
         in.close();
         ops.close();
     }

     catch(IOException ex)
             //EXCEPTION CAUGHT HERE
```

I was wondering, does anyone have any idea if this is an issue maybe with buffer sizes on a Linux box, or writing large file sizes for example and then trying to send it back down the wire.

Essentially this java based servlet writes xml to my c# programme.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some detail on the error too?

Comment: i didnt have time to print the error out before my boss left, all i new was it was one of these lines that cause the exception as i stuck a quick println in there, and the println just before this set of code executed also

Comment: @tom Surely you can't be expected to investigate anything without access or at least the stack trace of the exception. Without seeing anything, I'd probably guess that the path of the file contains \ instead of / and that's why you're getting an exception. But this is just a wild guess.

Comment: Well its the end of the day, i dont think i am suppsoed to do anything thoroughly. I just didnt no if there was anything in there that was obvious to you more experienced programmers that i could easily miss, or for example something thats specific to linux that i wouldnt ever no about. As i say, it worked perfectly when it was deployed as local host.

Comment: Why do you create an empty temporary file and then start reading from it?

Comment: i will post all the code - i just ommited some as i thought it wasnt necessary

Comment: Possibly, if you write to this temp file, the problem could be that you need to `out.close()` and `out.flush()` the stream so that OS get all the data. After that file.length() should return the right value.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error? Does it work if you load the URL in the browser?

Possible problems:

1. Given that it was working previously on another box, now on a new box the file coud not be found because it is in a different relative location.
2. Worked on windows machine, but not on Linux? Did you use windows path separators in a path to the file? "path\to\file" instead of "path/to/file"?
3. You don't have Content-type set to "application/xml" and C# client rejects it for some reason. (Test it in a browser).

Comment: Just to add i am currently testing this through the browser only, when i see it working in there i was going to start doing it through my programme again. Just to add,  file = File.createTempFile("temp", Long.toString(System.nanoTime())); which is made fine as the exception doesnt occur for another 6 or 7 lines on. Ihave updated the OP to show this

Comment: I believe you should add `writer.flush()` and `writer.close()` when done writing to it, so that data gets sent to OS.